# Trying to work with theme & struggling with thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, themes, thumbnails, editing

I'm doing some work with a theme and am struggling with trying to handle formatting. The original author used $post_thumb_url for getting the featured image, instead of the usual get_the_post_thumbnail(); ...

My knowledge is just enough to be dangerous, but I'm not finding ways to work with image size, alignment, etc, with $post_thumb_url ...

Comment: The information not enough, clearly $post_thumb_url is a variable. You need to check where it is declared. or even you can do var_dump($post_thumb_url); to see what it is returning.